# What to do when Breusch-Pagan shows heteroscedasticity but plot looks it might not?

Tags: r, regression, anova, heteroscedasticity

So I'm trying to run a Least-Squares Means with a covariate.  However when I run Breusch-Pagan test it shows heteroscedasticity even after either tukey or log2 transformation, however the plots seem fine.  Here are the plots. Reproducible codes below in R. Wanted to know what your opinion(s) are on how this data looks and what else I can try?

[image]

```
bd = read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/jbtabd372u8675c/hs.csv?dl=1", header=T)

bd$tuk = transformTukey(bd$value, plotit=FALSE)
bd$log2 = log2(bd$value)


bd.lm.tuk = lm(tuk ~ group + unspec , data = bd)
bd.lm.log2 = lm(log2 ~ group + unspec , data = bd)

test.tuk = bptest(bd.lm.tuk)
test.log2 = bptest ( bd.lm.log2)


bd$fit.log2 = bd.lm.log2$fitted.values
bd$res.log2 = bd.lm.log2$residuals

bd$fit.tuk = bd.lm.tuk$fitted.values
bd$res.tuk = bd.lm.tuk$residuals


glog2 = ggplot(data = bd, aes(y = res.log2, x = fit.log2, fill=group)) + 
    geom_point(aes ( color = group) ) + 
    ggtitle ( paste( "bptest: ", round ( test.log2$p.value, 4), "log2") )


gtuk = ggplot(data = bd, aes(y = res.tuk, x = fit.tuk, fill=group)) + 
    geom_point(aes ( color = group) ) + 
    ggtitle ( paste( "bptest: ", round ( test.tuk$p.value, 4), "tukey") )

grid.arrange ( glog2, gtuk, ncol=1)


result = lsmeans::lsmeans(bd.lm.log2,
                          pairwise ~ group,
                          adjust="tukey")

r = summary ( result )
```

Comment: Why deal with heteroskedasticity via transformations? That has not been the recommended approach to dealing with heteroskedasticity in linear regression for almost 40 years now. Use a robust covariance matrix estimator.

Comment: Suggest fitting the model using `nlme::gls` and a suitable weight function.

Comment: @rvl thanks but what is the benefit of going with gls over lm since the latter can also do weights?  I tried doing 1/sd of group as weight and it helps a bit.

Comment: @tchakravarty thanks, I'm confuse since this is the first I heard of using covariance matrix.  Do you mind linking a tutorial if you have one?

Comment: You can find a very nice introduction here: https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/5-4-hah.html, especially in the section - "Computation of Heteroskedasticity-Robust Standard Errors".

Answer (score 2):

White standard errors are a common way to deal with hetero (I think this is what tchakravarty  is suggesting). In terms of the original question tests can be wrong for a variety of reasons most obviously lack of statistical power.